# Rails 4 - select_tag pass parameter to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, html-select

I have two models, `Posts` and `Teams`, when the user creates a Post I want the user to select which team it should belong to. And I want to do it using a `select_tag`. What I currently have is (I use `HAML`):

```
= f.label :team_id, "Select team"
= select_tag :team_id, options_from_collection_for_select(current_user.teams, :id, :name)
```

In my controller:

```
def create

  # I want to pass :team_id here, but I'n not sure how...
  @team = current_user.teams.find post_params[:team_id]
  @post = @team.posts.build post_params
  @post.user = current_user
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Couldn't find Team without an ID
```

---

**Note**

I previously used radio buttons to achieve this, it looked like this (and worked):

```
- current_user.teams.each do |team|
  = f.radio_button 'team_id', team.id
  = team.name
```

So, how can I achieve the same thing using a `select_tag`?

Comment: Can you show us your `post_params` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `team_id` is an attribute of `post`, so when you create a Post record you have all post params wrapped into post hash, something like `:post => {:title => 'Some title', :team_id => 1}` etc.. so `team_id` is inside `post`:

```
@team = current_user.teams.find(params[:post][:team_id])
```

Comment: Almost correct, but but me in the right direction. `:team_id` wasn't i n the post hash. This instead worked: `@team = current_user.teams.find(params[:team_id])`

Comment: Well, good thing it worked, I could've give you a better answer if I had access to the request logs. Cheers ;)